# How to Unzip files recursively in Linux / DOS

Tags: windows, linux, shell-script, zip, recursive

I have a zipped folder which contains thousands of zipped folders contained in itself and that goes down the hierarchy, I have to unzip each and every file and place it in a single folder.

This task is platform independent either in linux or on windows.

Your help would be highly appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it the quick and dirty way and it worked for me. Create a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function rec_unzip {
unzip $1 && rm $1
for i in $(find . -name "*.zip"); do
    if [ -f $i ]
    then
         rec_unzip $i
    fi
done
}
rec_unzip $1
```

execute the script with `./script_name.sh first_zip_file.zip`.

You are free to modify it to supply target directories to unzip.